# Mathematical induction proof that $\forall{n}\in{N}:1(1!)+2(2!)+3(3!)+...+n(n!)=(n+1)!-1$

Tags: proof-verification, induction

Proof:

$$\forall{n}\in{N}:1(1!)+2(2!)+3(3!)+...+n(n!)=(n+1)!-1$$

**Step 1**

Prove *p(n)=>True* for *n=1*

$$1(1!)=(1+1)!-1$$

$$1=1$$

**Step 2**

*Assume by induction that (k)=>true*

$$\forall{k}\in{N}:1(1!)+2(2!)+3(3!)+...+k(k!)=(k+1)!-1$$

**Step 3**

*Prove p(k+1)=>true*

$$1(1!)+2(2!)+3(3!)+...+k(k!)=(k+1)!-1$$
$$1(1!)+2(2!)+3(3!)+...+k(k!)+(k+1)(k+1)!=(k+1)!-1+(k+1)(k+1)!$$

**Question**

**Is this the end of the demonstration?**

$$1(1!)+2(2!)+3(3!)+...+k(k!)+(k+1)(k+1)!=(k+1)!(k+2)-1)$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The last term should be $(k + 1)! \cdot (k+2) - 1 = (k + 2)! - 1$ instead of $(k+1)! \cdot (k+1) - 1$, but aside from that it is just fine.

Comment: Can you please show me how do you obtain the 2?

Comment: Look at your own steps, you just made a mistake.

Comment: Why does $(k+1)!(k+2)-1 => (k+2)!-1$?  Can you explain me please?

Comment: Because $(k+1)!$ is the product of all numbers less than or equal to $k+1$ and so $(k+1)! \cdot (k+2)$ is the product of all numbers less than or equal to $k+2$.  Please don't ask for a formal induction!